# Functional Graphics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, functional-programming, cgcontext

How do I route graphics rendering output on iOS with Swift? Coming from a functional language like Clojure, there seems to be plenty of implied side-effects and a single screen in the Swift and Objective-C drawing libraries that inject a context.

### Example

```
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: ...) // looks like a value
path.stroke() // wow, what just happened here, where did this render to? How would I have rendered to an image?
```

So, I see you can do this:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    return
}
context.saveGState()
context.translateBy(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)

path.stroke() // OK, so this must be drawing to the current context with an offset
context.restoreGState() // what does this do?
```

It seems to me it would be far cleaner to have this:

```
func drawThing(context: CGContext, radius: ...) {
    context.drawArc(arcCenter: ..., radius: radius, ...)
}
```

I'm hoping there is a more modern, functional way to mutate contexts over time.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you want do exist. You can call the various `add..` methods on a context to draw paths and the various `stroke...` and `fill...` methods to make the paths actually visible. You don't *have* to use `UIBezierPath`s.

Here's an example:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.strokeLineSegments(between: [.zero, CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)])
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation for all these methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to imperative programming :) I'm not aware of a functional library that would allow you to use graphic contexts, and even if there would be one, the language itself doesn't have full support for functional constructs (pure functions, monads, etc).

However, you could write a small wrapper around `CGContext` that would allow you some degree of control over the side effects of the functions you call:

```
struct CGContextDrawing {
    let commands: [(CGContext) -> Void]

    init(commands: [(CGContext) -> Void] = []) {
        self.commands = commands
    }
}

func appended(_ drawing: CGContextDrawing) -> (@escaping (CGContext) -> Void) -> CGContextDrawing {
    return { CGContextDrawing(commands: drawing.commands + [$0]) }
}

func move(_ drawing: CGContextDrawing) -> (CGPoint) -> CGContextDrawing {
    return { point in appended(drawing)({ $0.move(to: point) }) }
}

func line(_ drawing: CGContextDrawing) -> (CGPoint) -> CGContextDrawing {
    return { point in appended(drawing)({ $0.addLine(to: point) }) }
}

// this would be an impure function
func draw(_ drawing: CGContextDrawing) -> (CGContext) -> Void {
    return { context in  drawing.commands.forEach { $0(context) } }
}

// this would also be impure, to some extent
func drawToImage(_ drawing: CGContextDrawing) -> (CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    return { size in
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        draw(drawing)(context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Along with defining the composition and bind operators, this could result in some nice functional programming style. Although due to the language you might end up with some awkward/bloated constructs.